# Google Analytics for mobile App

Tags: google-analytics-api

There some question I would like to find out:

1. The list of iOS/Android App that are using Google Analytics
2. Does the app user realise the app is using Google Analytics

I am planning to use google analytics, but there may be privacy concerns,
I would like to find out how other apps handle it.

Much Appreciate with your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of privacy issues, you should mention that you're using mobile analytics in your terms and conditions.

Another thing- besides Google Analytics, I've encountered with a mobile analytics platform called [Appsee](http://www.appsee.com), and it seems to offer a more extensive solution than Google Analytics, including user recordings, Heatmaps and more.

Comment: thanks. I look at Appsee, the presentation is very attractive. seems for the Free version only 1000 session, the quota is too little. anyway. thanks~!